# How do i make this Foor loop work in this problem?

Tags: c++, loops

My problem requires a summation formula decreasing in numbers until it reaches the one I enter.

My code is currently not working and any solution would be greatly appreciated.

The following is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int c1 = 0, c2 = 0, c3 = 0, c4 = 0, n = 0, n2 = 0, n3 = 0, i = 0, k = 0, f = 0, c5 = 0, x = 0, y = 0, v = 0;

    cin >> n >> k;

    c1 = n - (k - 1);
    c3 = k;
    y = c1 - 1;

    f = (y * (y + 1)) / 2;

    cout << f << endl;

    // here everything works perfectly

    for (i = n; i <= c1; i--)
    { // all af this for fails i don't know why

        c2 = ceil(i / k);

        v = c2 - 1;

        c4 += (v * (v + 1)) / 2;

    }

    cout << c4 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Edit the page is https://omegaup.com/arena/problem/OMI-2017-Logias#problems

Comment: `c2=ceil(i/k);` if `i` and `k` are both integers is there a pont of using `ceil()`? Note: that the result of an integer division is an integer not a float.

Comment: Recommendation: Use descriptive variable names. Alphabet soup makes debugging harder than it needs to be. Since you have a debugging question, why make it harder on yourself?

Comment: In the `for` loop, should not it be `i >= c1` ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question if yoy want to correct it.

Comment: `ceil(i / k);` this doesn't do what you probably think it does. Read about integer division in C.

Answer (score 1):

- You are assigning `c1` value as subtracting `n` value with `k-1`.
  So always the `c1` value is lesser than `n`.
- Then, In for loop, you are initializing `i` value as `n`. and this
  condition `(i<=c1)` leads to fail in any case.